# RaspberryPi 3 - VLC stream has no audio on 1st try, works on 2nd try

Tags: server, sound, vlc, webcam, raspberrypi

I've installed Ubuntu server on my RPI3 and am now trying to stream audio and video from my USB webcam attached to it.

But when streaming, I seem to be unable to get audio working the first time I run VLC, though it works the second time and so on.

Here are the relevant [VLC logs](http://zubozrout.cz/raspberrypi.html) and what I think may be a relevant bit of the first log:

```
access_alsa demux warning: cannot read samples: Broken pipe
```

I should also point out that I need to run this prior to opening VLC:

```
v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=640,height=480,pixelformat=1
```

I do this in order to make sound work on the RPi - it seems odd that I don't need any such thing on my Ubuntu desktop. Anyway, that part is explained a bit [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29717/raspberry-pi-recognizes-logitech-c920-webcam-but-cant-do-anything/54460#54460).

Comment: I just found a reason to this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=15851 and has no known solution :/